# How to implement timer to make text visible for a certain time and then replace it with another text in Java?

Tags: java, timer, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

I am creating a mobile phone keypad. I used an array to create buttons.

For one of my buttons, I want "Dialling..." to appear on the JTextField for about 2 seconds on the click and then replace it with "No Signal" for about 2 more seconds and then clear the JTextField.

All this should be done by just 1 click. I know it is to do with timers but I can't seem to implement it.

I have something like this at the moment but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

{       
    if(e.getActionCommand() == "Dial")
    {
        timer.start();
        counter++;
        if(counter ==1)
        {
            text1.setText("Dialling . . .");    
            counter = 0;
        }   
        if(e.getsource() == timer)
        {
            text1.setText("No Signal");
            timer.stop();               
        }               
    }
```

Comment: you can't compare `String`s using ==. instead: if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Dial")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getActionCommand() == "Dial")
       {
      text1.setText("Dialling . . .");  
        }
       }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer); // delay one sec
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
text1.setText("No Signal");
   }
```

Comment: There is no actionCommand when a Timer fires. You just set the text without checking the actionCommand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it displays No Signal straight up when I click the button. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at this 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/45676/making-a-timer-0000-minutes-and-seconds.html